# Log-log density-colour plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a density plot with a given data and using log scales in the two axes x,y, using the version of Matplotlib 2.0.0. I have made the following code, the problem is that for the log plot case don't give the correct functional behaviour.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

init = 0.0
points = 500
final_value = 100
steep = (final_value-init)/points
list_values_x = np.arange(init,final_value,steep)
list_values_y = np.arange(init,final_value,steep)

#WE CREATE OUT DATA FILE

f1 = open("data.txt", "w")
for i in list_values_x:
    for j in list_values_y:
        f1.write( str(i) +" "+str(j)+" "+str(0.0001*(i**2+j**2)) +"\n")

f1.close()


#NOW WE OPEN THE FILE WITH THE DATA AND MAKE THE PLOT
x,y,temp = np.loadtxt('data.txt').T #Transposed for easier unpacking

nrows, ncols = points, points
grid = temp.reshape((nrows, ncols))

# LINEAR PLOT

fig1 = plt.imshow(grid, extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.max(), y.min()),
           interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.gist_rainbow)
plt.axis([x.min(), x.max(),y.min(),  y.max()])
plt.colorbar()
plt.suptitle('Example', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=16)

plt.show()

# LOG-LOG PLOT

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(8, 4))

ax1.imshow(grid, aspect="auto", extent=(1, 1e2, 1, 1e2), interpolation='nearest')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_title('Example with log scale')



plt.show()
```

The data that I am using in order to make the plot is irrelevant, it's just an example. So that, the first plot is given with a linear scale. The second plot is given with a log-log scale, but is clear that it's incorrect, the behaviour beetwen the two plots is absolutely different and I am using the same data. Moreover, I don't know how put a colorbar in the log-log plot

[image: example without log scale]

[image: example with log scale]

Any idea why this happens? Thanks for your attention.

PD: In order to build the log-log plot, I have used part of the code that apears in "Non-linear scales on image plots" given in (http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/whats_new.html#non-linear-scales-on-image-plots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the extent keyword and it with `extent=(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` makes more sense when additionally using `origin="lower"` in `imshow`. You might also want to set the limits for the axes, since the automatic feature does not work too well for log scales.

Here is the complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

points = 500
init = 0.0
final_value = 100
steep = (final_value-init)/points
x = np.arange(init,final_value,steep)
y = np.arange(init,final_value,steep)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = 0.0001*(X**2+Y**2)

fig, (ax, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))
# LINEAR PLOT
im = ax.imshow(Z, extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max() ),
           interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.gist_rainbow, origin="lower")
ax.set_title('lin scale')

#make colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
ax_cb = divider.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.add_axes(ax_cb)
fig.colorbar(im, cax = ax_cb, ax=ax)

# LOG-LOG PLOT
im1 = ax1.imshow(Z,  extent=(1, 1e2, 1, 1e2), 
           interpolation='nearest',cmap=cm.gist_rainbow, origin="lower")
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_xlim([1, x.max()])
ax1.set_ylim([1, y.max()])
ax1.set_title('log scale')

#make colorbar
divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
ax_cb1 = divider1.new_horizontal(size="5%", pad=0.05)
fig.add_axes(ax_cb1)
fig.colorbar(im1, cax = ax_cb1, ax=ax1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]